# Azure Active Directory Unity Authentication Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement Azure AD authentication into my Unity app. I have started with the code and documentation from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop . Their Visual Studio example project works fine, however when I try to use this code within my Unity project it fails when trying to run it.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };     
public static string ClientId = {...} // my azure app id
private static string Tenant = {...} // my tenant id

private async void AsyncLoginButton()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant;
        var app = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId, authority, TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());

        {...}

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);                 
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                textContent.text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{msalex}";
                Debug.Log(msalex);
            }         

        {...}
    }
```

with the following error - "Could not register the window class, win32 error 0":

[image]

After pressing OK on the above window it just gives a null reference at the line with AcquireTokenAsync.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.net45.WebUI+<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__16.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest+<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__10.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest+<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase+<RunAsync>d__16.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication+<AcquireTokenForLoginHintCommonAsync>d__22.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication+<AcquireTokenAsync>d__5.MoveNext () (at <a854dd38cefc420d850373110dec4a99>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
ApplioMGE.Login+<AsyncLoginButton>d__37.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Transitional/Login.cs:136)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:111)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:72)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:93)
```

I assume this happens when the code is trying to pop up the Microsoft Graph API window which asks for your credentials, but for some reason this doesn't work in Unity.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You should put code and error text into the question itself and not in an image. Also, what is the context of that code? Is it in a method that consumes the `AcquireTokenAsync` return value, or does it pass it on?

Comment: What is the value of `scope` that you're providing? Does it differ from the example project?

Comment: @Eliasar Thank you for your quick reply. There is no error text up to that point when the window shows up and everything is the same as the example project, which is why I kept it simple in my post, but I've edited it with the extra details you asked for.

Comment: Is your `scope` somehow null? Could you use a different `AcquireTokenAsync` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_PublicClientApplication_AcquireTokenAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Microsoft_Identity_Client_UIParent_

Comment: @Eliasar 
The scope is defined in the first line `string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };  ` , unless I'm misunderstand what you mean by `scope`.

And I'm not sure how to use other versions of the method `AcquireTokenAsync` as I don't know what to pass in the other parameters. Wouldn't they all try to use the Graph API anyway?

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.Identity.Client` are you using? I'm also seeing some issues and fixes on their github for that project. [Nullreferenceexception on PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/617) and [UIParent Fix](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/pull/1428)

Comment: @Eliasar I was using the latest stable version - 2.7.1. I've just tried 1.1.4 as described in the conversation you provided but with no success, getting the same error. The UIParent doesn't seem relevant as I'm trying to make this work for PC at the moment, not iOS.

Comment: My guess is that the UIParent is to give a callback to any window that called the authentication. If it's null, that would explain the null reference exception